# AzureReader2 and ImageResizer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-blob-storage, imageresizer

We are using **AzureReader2** to which we have downloaded all our images.
Also, we are using image re-sizer to resize the images on web site.

I would like to know what could be the security issues that may arise with **AzureReader2** and `ImageResizer` and how can we prevent them.

I am aware of Cache getting overflowed with Image re-sizing.
What could be other security issues.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question concerning ImageResizer, neither CPU nor RAM can generally be overloaded during a (D)DOS attack. Memory allocation is contiguous, meaning an image cannot be processed unless there is around 15-30% free RAM remaining. Under the default pipeline, only 2 cores are used for image processing, so a regular server will not see CPU saturation either.

In general, there are far more effective ways to attack an ASP.NET website than though ImageResizer. Any database-heavy page is more likely to be a weak point, as the memory allocations are smaller and easier to saturate the server with.

Disk space starvation can be mitigated by enabling autoClean="true".

If you're a high-profile site with lots of determined ill-wishers, you can also consider the following:

Use request signing - only URLs generated by your server will be accepted.
Use the Presets plugin to white-list defined permitted command combinations.
Both of these reduce development agility and limit your options for responsive web design, so unless you have actually been attacked in the past, I don't suggest them.

In practice, (D)DOS attacks against dynamic imaging software are rarely useful at bringing down anything except — temporarily — uncached images — even when running under the same application pool. Since visited images tend to be cached, the actual effect is rather laughable.

Comment: I have already saw this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799102/image-resizer-best-practice-for-security. What I am looking for, is there a way to restrict no.of redirects to the same image?some ill-wishers may continuously load the images can I implement any restriction in AzureReader or with imageResizing?